# Adding a Task in MS Project at a specific location with VBA through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have and Excel file with all current tasks. New tasks maybe be added at any position. I want to update my MS Project file from Excel by adding missing tasks. Using `.Tasks.Add("name from Excel")` will as a new Task in MS Project at the bottom. How can i add new Task at a specific location in the middle using VBA from Excel? Can I use `SelectRow` and `InsertTask` in VBA code from Excel somehow?

*EDIT
Forgot to mention, `.Tasks.Add` does not let me use a 2nd argument, like it says in documentation.

```
With mpp
    .Tasks.Add ("name from Excel", RowNumber)
End With
```

This code will have the line with `.Tasks.Add ("name from Excel", RowNumber)` in red. If i remove the 2nd argument, it's fine and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the docs for [Tasks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks.add) shows that the method takes an optional second argument *Before*:

> The position of the task in its containing collection. The default
> value is the position of the last item in the collection. (data type
> Long)

Utilize the second argument and pass in the ID of the task before which the new task should be added. For example:

```
With mpp
    .Tasks.Add "name from Excel", RowNumber
End With
```

Or

```
Dim t As MSProject.Task
With mpp
    Set t = .Tasks.Add("name from Excel", RowNumber)
End With
```

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot to mention. It does not let me add a 2nd argument like that. Text becomes red in VBA.

Comment: Remove the parentheses since you aren't returning an object. I updated my answer based on your code update.

Comment: Thank you very much Rachel. I tried both your solutions and both do exactly what they need to.